# Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I updated to Spring Boot 3 in a project that uses the Keycloak Spring Adapter. Unfortunately, it doesn't start because the  `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which was first deprecated in Spring Security and then removed. Is there currently another way to implement security with Keycloak? Or to put it in other words: How can I use Spring Boot 3 in combination with the Keycloak adapter?

I searched the Internet, but couldn't find any other version of the adapter.

Comment: Latest updates on the Keycloak adapter deprecation can be found here: https://www.keycloak.org/2023/03/adapter-deprecation-update.html

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can't use Keycloak adapters with spring-boot 3 for the reason you found, plus a few others related to transitive dependencies. As [most Keycloak adapters were deprecated in early 2022](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187), it is very likely that no update will be published to fix that.

Instead, use [spring-security 6 libs for OAuth2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html). **Don't panic, it's an easy task with spring-boot**.

In the following, I'll consider you have a good understanding of OAuth2 concepts and know exactly why you need to configure an OAuth2 client or an OAuth2 resource server. **In case of doubt, please refer to the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) section of [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)**.

I'll only detail here the configuration of **servlet** application as a resource server, and then as a client, for **a single Keycloak realm**, with and then without `spring-addons-starter-oidc`, a Spring Boot starter of mine. Browse directly to the section you are interested in (but be prepared to write much more code if you don't want to use "my" starter).

Also refer to [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) for different use-cases like:

- accepting tokens issued by multiple realms or instances (known in advance or dynamically created in a trusted domain)
- reactive applications (webflux), like `spring-cloud-gateway` for instance
- apps publicly serving both a REST API and a server-side rendered UI to consume it
- advanced access-control rules
- BFF pattern
- ...

## 1. OAuth2 Resource Server

**App exposes a REST API secured with access tokens**. It is consumed by an OAuth2 REST client. A few sample of such clients:

- another Spring application configured as an OAuth2 client and using `WebClient`, `@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate` or alike to query the resource server
- a **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend (BFF) like a `spring-cloud-gateway` instance configured with `oauth2Login()` and the `TokenRelay` filter
- development tools like Postman capable of fetching OAuth2 tokens and issuing REST requests
- Javascript based application configured as a "public" OAuth2 client with a library like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) (but warning, [this is now discouraged](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390))

### 1.1. With `spring-addons-starter-oidc`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
origins: http://localhost:4200
issuer: http://localhost:8442/realms/master

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
            prefix: ROLE_
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        resourceserver:
          cors:
          - path: /my-resources/**
            allowed-origin-patterns: ${origins}
          permit-all: 
          - "/actuator/health/readiness"
          - "/actuator/health/liveness"
          - "/v3/api-docs/**"
```

Prefix for realm roles in the conf above are there only for illustration purposes, you might remove it. The CORS configuration would need some refinements too.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig { }
```

**Nothing more is needed to configure a resource-server with fine tuned CORS policy and authorities mapping. Bootiful, isn't it?**.

As you can guess from the `ops` property being an array, this solution is actually compatible with "static" multi-tenancy: you can declare as many trusted issuers as you need and it can be heterogeneous (use different claims for username and authorities).

Also, this solution is compatible with reactive application: `spring-addons-starter-oidc` will detect it from what is on the classpath and adapt its security auto-configuration.

### 1.2. With just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- used when converting Keycloak roles to Spring authorities -->
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8442/realms/master
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> jwtAuthenticationConverter) throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter)));

        // Enable and configure CORS
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource("http://localhost:4200")));

        // State-less session (state in access-token only)
        http.sessionManagement(sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        // Disable CSRF because of state-less session-management
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());

        // Return 401 (unauthorized) instead of 302 (redirect to login) when
        // authorization is missing or invalid
        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Bearer realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
        }));

        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(accessManagement -> accessManagement
            .requestMatchers("/actuator/health/readiness", "/actuator/health/liveness", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
    }

    private UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource(String... origins) {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(origins));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(List.of("*"));

        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/my-resources/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> {

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            return Stream.of("$.realm_access.roles", "$.resource_access.*.roles").flatMap(claimPaths -> {
                Object claim;
                try {
                    claim = JsonPath.read(jwt.getClaims(), claimPaths);
                } catch (PathNotFoundException e) {
                    claim = null;
                }
                if (claim == null) {
                    return Stream.empty();
                }
                if (claim instanceof String claimStr) {
                    return Stream.of(claimStr.split(","));
                }
                if (claim instanceof String[] claimArr) {
                    return Stream.of(claimArr);
                }
                if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(claim.getClass())) {
                    final var iter = ((Collection) claim).iterator();
                    if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                        return Stream.empty();
                    }
                    final var firstItem = iter.next();
                    if (firstItem instanceof String) {
                        return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream();
                    }
                    if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(firstItem.getClass())) {
                        return (Stream<String>) ((Collection) claim).stream().flatMap(colItem -> ((Collection) colItem).stream()).map(String.class::cast);
                    }
                }
                return Stream.empty();
            })
            /* Insert some transformation here if you want to add a prefix like "ROLE_" or force upper-case authorities */
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
            .map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast).toList();
        }
    }

    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class SpringAddonsJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {

        @Override
        public JwtAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
            final var authorities = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter().convert(jwt);
            final String username = JsonPath.read(jwt.getClaims(), "preferred_username");
            return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, username);
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to being much more verbose than preceding one, this solution is also less flexible:

- not adapted to multi-tenancy (multiple Keycloak realms or instances)
- hardcoded allowed origins
- hardcoded claim names to fetch autorities from
- hardcoded "permitAll" path matchers

## 2. OAuth2 Client

**App exposes any kind of resources secured with sessions** (not access tokens). It is consumed directly by a browser (or any other user agent capable of maintaining a session) without the need of a scripting language or OAuth2 client lib (authorization-code flow, logout and token storage are handled by Spring on the server). Common uses-cases are:

- applications with server-side rendered UI (with Thymeleaf, JSF, or whatever)
- `spring-cloud-gateway` used as **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend: configured with `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay` filter (hides OAuth2 tokens from the browser and replaces session cookie with an access token before forwarding a request to downstream resource server(s)).

### 2.1. With `spring-addons-starter-oidc`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-starter-oidc</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
issuer: http://localhost:8442/realms/master
client-id: spring-addons-confidential
client-secret: change-me
client-uri: http://localhost:8080

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${issuer}
        registration:
          keycloak-login:
            provider: keycloak
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      oidc:
        ops:
        - iss: ${issuer}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
          - path: $.realm_access.roles
          - path: $.resource_access.*.roles
        client:
          client-uri: ${client-uri}
          security-matchers: /**
          permit-all:
          - /
          - /login/**
          - /oauth2/**
          csrf: cookie-accessible-from-js
          post-login-redirect-path: /home
          post-logout-redirect-path: /
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
}
```

As for resource server, this solution works in reactive applications too.

There is also an optional support for multi-tenancy on clients: allow a user to be logged in simultaneously on several OpenID Providers, on which he might have different usernames (`subject` by default, which is a UUID in Keycloak, and changes with each realm).

### 2.2. With just `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- used when converting Keycloak roles to Spring authorities -->
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```yaml
issuer: http://localhost:8442/realms/master
client-id: spring-addons-confidential
client-secret: change-me

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${issuer}
        registration:
          keycloak-login:
            provider: keycloak
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${client-id}
            client-secret: ${client-secret}
            scope: openid,profile,email,offline_access
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain
            clientSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository)
                    throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        http.logout(logout -> {
            logout.logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository));
        });
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(ex -> ex
                .requestMatchers("/", "/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/nice.html").hasAuthority("NICE")
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }

    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    static class GrantedAuthoritiesMapperImpl implements GrantedAuthoritiesMapper {

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            authorities.forEach(authority -> {
                if (OidcUserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    final var oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                    final var issuer = oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken().getClaimAsURL(JwtClaimNames.ISS);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(extractAuthorities(oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken().getClaims()));

                } else if (OAuth2UserAuthority.class.isInstance(authority)) {
                    try {
                        final var oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                        final var userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();
                        final var issuer = new URL(userAttributes.get(JwtClaimNames.ISS).toString());
                        mappedAuthorities.addAll(extractAuthorities(userAttributes));

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            });

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };

        @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        private static Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Map<String, Object> claims) {
            /* See resource server solution above for authorities mapping */
        }
    }
}
```

## 3. What is [`spring-addons-starter-oidc`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#spring-addons-starter-oidc) and why using it

This starter is a standard [Spring Boot starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-auto-configuration) with additional application properties used to auto-configure default beans and provide it to Spring Security. **It is important to note that the auto-configured `@Beans` are almost all `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` which enables you to override it in your conf**.

It is open-source and you can change everything it pre-configures for you (refer to the Javadoc, the starter READMEs, or the many samples). **You should read the starters source before deciding not to trust it**, it is not that big. Start with [`imports` resource](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports), it defines what is loaded by Spring Boot for auto-configuration.

In my opinion (and as demonstrated above), Spring Boot auto-configuration for OAuth2 can be pushed one step further to:

- make OAuth2 configuration more portable: **with a configurable authorities converter, switching from an OIDC provider to another is just a matter of editing properties** (Keycloak, Auth0, Cognito, Azure AD, etc.)
- ease app deployment on different environments: **CORS configuration is controlled from properties file**
- reduce drastically the amount of Java code (things get even more complicated if you are in multi-tenancy scenario)
- support more than just one issuer by default
- reduce chances of misconfiguration (for instance, it is frequent to see sample configurations with disabled CSRF protection on clients, or wasting resources with sessions on endpoints secured with access tokens)

Comment: Thank you. That looks quite bootiful and easy to migrate to. Will try this approach.

Comment: I am currently implementing your suggestions. The rest service with the resource dependency starts but when visiting any url I am getting the error that no JwtDecoder is available. https://gitlab.com/samuel1998.schwanzer/SmartOrganizr/-/tree/migrate/oauth2

Comment: My local configuration looks like that:

```spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=smartorganizr
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=dzmKY0QUuLflQBeceMIhPCr8gE5AN9YF
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://192.168.2.33/realms/master```

Comment: Sorry. I want to create a client. It should have the same configuration as a keycloak confidential client. You can find an updated version on gitlab. This is my yaml:

https://pastebin.com/GFMqxPPE
with password: sGAydP4AyT

Comment: Anybody else getting the error for the uiFilterChain, that a bean of type ClientRegistrationRepository cannot be found?

Comment: You are probably missing a dependency: `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`

Comment: Except that this solution does not have the self contained authorization solution. The essence of these adapters previously was that you upload a sophisticated authorization rrule set for your services into keycloak, like roles, policy enforcement, etc and the keycloak adapter could authorize methods accordingly. With this standard spring approach, it will not work. Would be hell of a lot tedious work to make it work. There is a conversation about it: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/11681

Comment: In short I am quote furious and mad about these responses everwhere on the internet, everybody shows the standard oidc + spring boot oauth2 solutions, and they forget that most of the real world usages of the keycloak security adapters involved heavily more sopshisticated features, than being a simple authentication server. It is like using a rocket ship to go home after work.

Comment: I contributed in the thread you mention why this authorization service is, in my opinion, a bad thing. This kind of rocket ship will never fly you to the moon: it is way too adherent to Keycloak, hardly testable, and inefficient. Just as introspection, it requires a call to authorization server for each and every request, which introduces latency and poorly scales.

Comment: It is possible to do advanced access control with no adherence to Keycloak. I did it for a set of Healthcare professionals web services requiring authorization delegation between users for specific structures. Of course editing roles or permissions delegation does not require a restart and spring security DSL enhancement are defined at a single place for all services.

Comment: At the method `apiFilterChain`, I think there should be `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>` instead `Converter<JWT, AbstractAuthenticationToken>`. Thanks for this answer. This one is great.

Comment: how to use policy enforce in your add-on?

Comment: You call authorization service REST endpoint with a REST client like WebClient, @FeignClient, RestClient. But honestly, I wouldn't do that: refer to this answer why https://stackoverflow.com/a/75647048/619830

Comment: if we have a OAuth2 Client, is it possible to access our endpoints through Postman?
I have no problems in browser, when I access an endpoint it redirects to the login Keycloak page. But also in Postman, even if I send an access token in the Authorization header, I only get the login page as a response.

Comment: Read my answer again, more carefuly: requests to clients are secured with sessions, not access tokens. Configure a resource server if you need requests to be secured with access tokens or refer to my tutorials if you need to mix client and resource server configurations

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the follow up to Spring Boot 3.1/Security 6.1.

Comment: @ch4mp I tried to use your starter for webflux but when I access route "/admin" and the user have role admin it give me access denied. any suggestion about how to fix that.

Comment: With that level of details, it's impossible to find the cause of your issue. My guess is you used `hasRole("admin")` which requires exactly `ROLE_admin` authority. To have this authority, given the token contains the `admin` role (not `ADMIN`), use `prefix: ROLE_` property at the same level as the `path` one in application properties (a different prefix can be configured for each JSON-Path). Otherwize, use `hasAuthority` or `hasAnyAuthority` instead of `hasRole` or `hasAnyRole`.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned about ROLE_ but never worked (could you share a link to how prefix can be configured for each json-path), it worked with "hasAuthority & hasAnyAuthority.

Comment: @Ch4mp could you please share how to use gateway with keycloak to login/signup (for microservices), I tried your tutorials (reactive-resource-server & bff) but still I had hard time, could you please suggest articles or source codes about that. Thanks

Comment: I added illustrations of prefix usage in the response. OAuth2 login on a resource server is a nonsense, read the main readme for some OAuth2 background. If you followed the Keycloak setup REAME, then the BFF project should start and login work.

Comment: @Ch4mp could you please check this code https://github.com/magician20/learningcircle I want to know why gateway not redirect request to greeting service & how could I handle login and register from gateway service

Comment: If you are calling `/api/test`, it is listed in `permit-all` => no authorization required => unauthorized requests are not redirected

Comment: @Ch4mp Thanks for your feedback, still not working

Comment: Do you have any similar guide for openID connect. I'm trying to migrate my springboot applications to springboot 3.x and want to know how to integrate keycloak openid connect.

Comment: OpenID is OAuth2, and all starters listed in the answer are using **O**pen**ID** **C**onnect to fetch authorization server OAuth2 configuration and JWT public signing keys. What exactly do you expect in addition to what is implemented above?

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have one additonal question. Why can I only map the authorities with resource_access from ID Tokens.
I would prefer to have that RBAC information only in the AccessToken rather than the ID Token.
I want to protect some resources (xhtml sites) with client-roles. But as i understand the Code in OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider or OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider
SpringBoot3 forces me to map these information into ID-Token on Keycloak side. I guess the KeycloakAdapter (SpringBoot2) handled that differently

Comment: Audience and purpose are not the same for ID and access tokens. Short answer is that ID tokens are intended to be read by clients and access tokens by resource servers. ID tokens should be used only to get some information about the identified user, not to grant access to resources. Access tokens are intended to grant access to resources: allow a client holding it to act on behalf of a user on a specific resource server. This differences make access token much more sensitive (if leaked, user identity can be stolen)

Comment: Because of the above, and because access tokens should be considered opaque on the client, Spring security **on OAuth2 clients** reads claims from either the ID token when available from the userinfo endpoint otherwize. **You can configure Keycloak to add client roles to ID tokens** (`clients -> your-client -> Client scopes -> your-client-dedicated -> Add mapper -> predifind -> client roles`, you then open the mapper details and enable Add to ID token and userinfo).

Comment: This will allow to read user roles on clients and adapt UI (hide menus, buttons and so on), not to filter accessible resources. Again, this roles should be checked again on the resource server, reading claims in an access token (JWT) or introspected from it (any format).

Comment: Thanks ch4amp, your explanation about ID and AccessTokens matches with my view on these. 
As you said, ID tokens should only have personal data and no role claims. 
Because of that I am still confused why SpringBoot3 does not provide the ability to extract roles form the AccessToken (as OAuth Client)
Mapping client-roles on Keycloak side to ID Token works, but i don't like this solution :(
I guess configuring my JSF SpringBoot3 App as Resource Server + OAuth Client makes no sense (I have to choose)?

Comment: "ID tokens should only have personal data and no role claims" why that? I didn't write that (and don't agree). When I write "access tokens should be considered opaque on the client", it means **don't try to validate / decode / introspect an access token as a client**. JSF apps are primarily OAuth2 clients with `oauth2Login`. However, it could make sense to secure the pages (rendered templates) with the main "client" `SecurityFilterChain` and, if you want to publicly expose a REST API (but only in that case), a second "resource server" `SecurityFilterChain` (see my tutorials for a sample).

Comment: Okay this was my interpretation of "ID tokens should be used only to get some information about the identified user, not to grant access to resources".
Is there a reason why the AccessToken should not be decoded/validated? I mean, the deprecated KeycloakAdapter implementation and the latest Elytron implementation (JEE) do decode the AccessToken and use the role information.

Comment: For your "2.2." could you please add the imports as well? I have added the given dependency but still I can't seem to find most of these classes. Using Springboot 3.1.5. So not sure why you have left out the imports of the piece of code.

Comment: Working projects (with imports and complete `pom.xml`) in the samples and [tutorials on my repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials). The  closest to `2.2` in this answer is the tutorial  named `servlet-client`

Answer (score 5):

Use the standard Spring Security OAuth2 client instead of a specific Keycloak adapter and `SecurityFilterChain` instead of `WebSecurityAdapter`.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class OAuth2SecurityConfig {

@Bean
fun customOauth2FilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    log.info("Configure HttpSecurity with OAuth2")

    http {
        oauth2ResourceServer {
            jwt { jwtAuthenticationConverter = CustomBearerJwtAuthenticationConverter() }
        }
        oauth2Login {}

        csrf { disable() }

        authorizeRequests {
            // Kubernetes
            authorize("/readiness", permitAll)
            authorize("/liveness", permitAll)
            authorize("/actuator/health/**", permitAll)
            // ...
            // everything else needs at least a valid login, roles are checked at method level
            authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
        }
    }

    return http.build()
}
```

And then in `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          abc:
            issuer-uri: https://keycloak.../auth/realms/foo
        registration:
          abc:
            client-secret: ...
            provider: abc
            client-id: foo
            scope: [ openid, profile, email ]
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://keycloak.../auth/realms/foo
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your configuration. I will try that way. Keycloak already announced moving away from their own adapter.

Comment: Roles mapping is missing and this will we be a problem as soon as any role based access-control is required (`@PreAuthorise` expressions or `authoriseRequests` in security conf) . Also,  this covers only part of the cases: resource-servers (REST APIs) are not covered.

Comment: You mention in your code a method that reads CustomBearerJwtAuthenticationConverter(). Where do I get that method from?

Comment: Just implement Spring's interface. You might find inspiration from the Authentication converter in my answer for resource-servers.

Answer (score 2):

Using Keycloak adapters is not possible because the `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` inherited from the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class, which was deprecated in Spring Security and subsequently removed in the newer release.

I have published a detailed article on integrating Keycloak with Spring Boot 3.0 on Medium, which provides a step-by-step guide on how to integrate Keycloak with Spring Boot 3.0.

This guide is particularly helpful for those who are new to integrating Keycloak with Spring Boot 3.0 or migrating to Spring Boot 3.0 from an older version.

You can check out the article (https://medium.com/geekculture/using-keycloak-with-spring-boot-3-0-376fa9f60e0b) for a comprehensive explanation of the integration process.
[image]

Hope this helps! If you have any questions, further clarifications or suggestions, Please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Do you realize thar your article covers only resource-servers and only *realm" roles, right? (when the answer above covers clients **and** clients roles too...)

Comment: I read your article and it works fine with spring-boot-starter-oath2-resource-server :) but still blocked with spring-boot-starter-oath2-client , it returns always a 404 ! 
Do you have a tutorial using spring-boot-starter-oath2-client with Thymleaf ?

Comment: Hi @Aguid. As I described in the article, if you use it with Thymleaf, you must use oath2-client. Currently, I don't have a tutorial to guide you but I will write one.

Comment: Hello Yasas and thank you for the helpful tutorial.. I have implemented the code you have mentioned in the tutorial but i still get an unauthorized access when i want to access to the user URL and I have double checked that I have assigned the user role to the user..

Comment: Update, my problem was solved with configuring the application.properties with the keycloak realm settings

Comment: Hi @GhassenJemaî Thanks for the feedback and happy that you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: I too followed Yasa code. Works except for matching the actuator endpoints with a role.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak adapters are deprecated and there will not be any future updates or fixes as announce by [Keycloak Team](https://www.keycloak.org/2023/03/adapter-deprecation-update) .

It is recommended to use Spring Security provided [OAuth2 and OpenID](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/index.html) Connect support.

Answer (score -1):

Keycloak 21.0.0 have introduced some new changes to support Spring Security 6.x.x and Spring Boot 3.x.x.. Here is a [reference to that](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/)

Comment: The documentation is deprecated since it extends from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapater you still can use the oauth2 client dependency with spring security

Comment: Isn't it still the [same](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_spring_security_adapter)?

Comment: yes the docs are pretty much deprecated since they implement the WebSecurityConfigurationAdapater

Answer (score -1):

Based on different resources and whole weekend, spent on solving this new issue, I managed to find perfectly working solution.

I defined 2 roles: user and administrator on client level (not realm) and assigned to different users.

- JDK 17
- Keycloak 22.0.0.
- Spring Boot 3.1.1

Here is the working solution for:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration {
    @Value("${keycloak.resource}")
    private String keycloakClientName;
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> {
            authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
        .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer
            .jwt(jwtConfigurer -> {
                jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
            })
        );

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    private Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken> jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new KeycloakRealmRoleConverter());

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    }

    private class KeycloakRealmRoleConverter implements Converter<Jwt, Collection<GrantedAuthority>> {
        private Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public Collection<GrantedAuthority> convert(Jwt jwt) {
            final Map<String, Object> resourceAccess = (Map<String, Object>) jwt.getClaims().get("resource_access");

            if (resourceAccess != null) {
                final Map<String, Object> clientAccess = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get(OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration.this.keycloakClientName);

                if (clientAccess != null) {
                    grantedAuthorities = ((List<String>) clientAccess.get("roles")).stream()
                            .map(roleName -> "ROLE_" + roleName) // Prefix to map to a Spring Security "role"
                            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                }
            }

            return grantedAuthorities;
        }
    }
}
```

Keycloak configuration in properties:

```
keycloak:
  authServerUrl: http://<your_keycloak_host>:8989
  realm: <your_realm>
  resource: <your_client>
  useResourceRoleMappings: true
  cors: true
  corsMaxAge: 1000
  corsAllowedMethods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET
  sslRequired: none
  bearerOnly: true
  publicClient: true
  principalAttribute: preferred_username
  credentials:
    secret: '{cipher}<your_encrypted_secret>'
```

And test controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/test")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String allAccess() {
        return "Public content";
    }

    @GetMapping("/endpoint1")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('user')")
    public String endpoint1() {
        return "User board";
    }

    @GetMapping("/endpoint2")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('administrator')")
    public String endpoint2() {
        return "Administrator board";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically only part of the accepted answer (the resource server half), most of the `keycloak` properties are not used (only `keycloak.resource` is), and your code seems to require the `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` which are missing from your snippets. Also, in a resource server filter-chain, you should disable sessions (and CSRF protection), and make sure that 401 is returned to unauthorized requests. In short, if you had read the answer (and maybe followed the links), you'd have saved a weekend.