# Keycloak asks for login credentials even when a valid token is provided

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak to secure a Spring Boot API using Spring Security. The API is running on port `8080` and Keycloak is on port `8081`. This is my filter chain:

```java
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/posts*").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        http.oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");

        return http.build();
    }
```

When I try to `POST` to `/api/posts` from Insomnia, It shows me the login screen even though I provided valid credentials.
[image: Insomnia screenshot]
(The access token is also there but it's not in the screenshot)

application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=backend
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8081/realms/test
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

Keycloak client config:
[image: Keycloak client config]

Comment: This answer will solve your problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to secure your API with tokens received from Keycloak, you should use the `oauth2ResourceServer` directive in your security configuration. You're using `oauth2Login`. So in the security filter chain, you should have something like this:

```java
@Value("${pring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri}")
String issuerUri;

...

.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
    oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(jwt ->
        jwt.decoder(JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri))
    )
);
```

Have a look at this tutorial we've created at Curity that shows how to create a Spring Boot API protected with JWTs: https://curity.io/resources/learn/spring-boot-api/ You can have a look at the complete solution there.

Comment: In this tutorial, authorities mapping is Spring's default one: from `scp` claim only when the `role` claim should probably considered too. I demo how to do it in [my own tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) from Java conf (with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`) or just properties (with a starter of my own which is a very thin wrapper arround `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`)