# Keycloak with Spring Boot based on roles does not work, which were assigned to the user in keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I have configured the use of **Keycloak** without using a spring adapter. Since it is deprecated. I created in the console of **Keycloak**: a **REALM**, a **user**, and add **roles** for the user.

[image]

[image]

- user
  Then I created a user and added to him the roles that I created earlier here.

[image]

[image]

- docker

```yaml
....
  keycloak:
    container_name: blog
    depends_on:
      keycloakdb:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${POSTGRESQL_DB}
      DB_USER: ${POSTGRESQL_USER}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRESQL_PASS}
      KEYCLOAK_USER: ${KEYCLOAK_USER}
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: ${KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD}
      DB_VENDOR: ${DB_VENDOR}
      DB_ADDR: ${DB_ADDR}
      DEBUG_PORT: ${DEBUG_PORT}
      DB_PORT: ${DB_PORT}
      TZ: ${TZ}
      DEBUG: ${DEBUG}
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
.....
```

here is the application configuration

- pom.xml

```xml
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.guide</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-postgres-quick-guide</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>keycloak-postgres-quick-guide</name>
    <description>keycloak-postgres-quick-guide</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.17.6</testcontainers.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
        <keycloak.version>20.0.2</keycloak.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
...
  
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

- security

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/customers*", "/users*")
                .hasRole("READ")
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

- controller

```java
    @GetMapping(path = "/customers")
    public String customers(Principal principal, Model model) {

        addCustomers();

        Iterable<Customer> customers = customerRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
        model.addAttribute("username", principal.getName());

        return "customers";
    }
```

- application.yml

```yaml
spring:

  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
        registration:
          keycloak:
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: loggin-app
            scope: openid
```

[image]
[image]

however, when trying to access a protected resource, I get an error :

> Sending OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [user-spring-app], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=yGjLEXdKSgOC3J8_QfLyrw, sub=26e4c1c7-cb02-4628-bae9-7a370b53c067, email_verified=false, iss=http://localhost:28080/auth/realms/SpringBootKeycloak, typ=ID, preferred_username=user-spring-app, nonce=yzqik3W-aQtCjP6nQGt-N2CbnyI7O7smrt6mLOZNXY8, sid=07dbaa6a-826c-4139-a956-62a477f6eefe, aud=[loggin-app], acr=1, azp=loggin-app, auth_time=2022-12-21T08:22:10Z, exp=2022-12-21T08:27:10Z, session_state=07dbaa6a-826c-4139-a956-62a477f6eefe, iat=2022-12-21T08:22:10Z, jti=93f19918-bc4a-4435-bbcd-578f7ca2ed36}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=A0B52BA34017AD4C0183CA1DD48420B8], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]] to access denied handler since access is denied
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

I am not observing the roles that I have assigned to the user

> Principal=Name: [user-spring-app], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]],

I am trying to understand how **keycloak** works, but so far there is only fragmentary information. The example that I found is outdated (the spring-boot-**Keycloak**-*adapter* deprecated now). In addition, I have seen different approaches, someone uses **hasAuthority()**, and someone uses **hasRole()**, however, I did not understand how it works in relation to **Keycloak**.

[image]
[image]

[image]
Does anyone have an understanding of how to fix this and explain the principle of such work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have to:

1. Configure keycloak to put role inside the id token.
2. Define a mapper to map the role inside the id token to the spring security role.

Let's do it:

1. Configure keycloak: My version is 20.x, my client is acme

Go to your keycloak realm -> Client -> Open your client -> Tab "Client scopes" -> In the table, click on the "acme-dedicated"

[image]

Add mapper -> Realm Roles

[image]

Uncheck and check **Add to ID token**: the checkbox may be checked by default but it isn't activated, we have to manually uncheck then check it again. Once done, click one **Save**.

[image]

You can go to **Client scope** -> **Evaluate** and verify that the role is present in the ID token.

2. OK, now let configure spring boot to map keycloak role to spring security role.

To do it, add the following code to your class SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM = "realm_access";
    private static final String ROLES_CLAIM = "roles";

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
        ...
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapperForKeycloak() {
        return authorities -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            var authority = authorities.iterator().next();
            boolean isOidc = authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority;

            if (isOidc) {
                var oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) authority;
                var userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();

                if (userInfo.hasClaim(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM)) {
                    var realmAccess = userInfo.getClaimAsMap(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM);
                    var roles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.get(ROLES_CLAIM);
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }
            } else {
                var oauth2UserAuthority = (OAuth2UserAuthority) authority;
                Map<String, Object> userAttributes = oauth2UserAuthority.getAttributes();

                if (userAttributes.containsKey(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM)) {
                    var realmAccess = (Map<String, Object>) userAttributes.get(REALM_ACCESS_CLAIM);
                    var roles = (Collection<String>) realmAccess.get(ROLES_CLAIM);
                    mappedAuthorities.addAll(generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(roles));
                }
            }
            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }

    Collection<GrantedAuthority> generateAuthoritiesFromClaim(Collection<String> roles) {
        return roles.stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

FYI: I don't use keycloak java adapter because it will be deprecated soon. I use oauth2-client with spring security. This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Good lucks !

Comment: I have for the created client, on its tab Client scopes - empty. (see the picture above). I don't understand what needs to be done ? I have a slightly different interface, I use the latest version of image: jboss/keycloak:latest .

Comment: I have selected one of the built-in protocol mappers - realm roles. I corrected it as you offer above.

Comment: Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=9E2258CCE4710BE568C8292CE9B42A5A], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_default-roles-springbootkeycloak, ROLE_offline_access, ROLE_ROLE_USER, ROLE_user, ROLE_uma_authorization, ROLE_read]] to access denied handler since access is denied

Comment: it turned out that the case of the letters in the name of the role, which was designated in, is important.hasRole("read"). thanks

Comment: This answer is the way to secure a Spring **client** application (no REST endpoint), as asked. To secure a resource-server (app exposing a REST API), see this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830

Comment: Thanks. I followed the tutorial here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak and interestingly this is not described there so the whole role based auth was not working.

Comment: Great answer, the only thing that may be wrong is that as we add the roles in the ID token, we should not retrieve the user info in the `userAuthoritiesMapperForKeycloak` method but the ID token instead. So I replaced the line `var userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getUserInfo();` by `var userInfo = oidcUserAuthority.getIdToken();`.