# Keycloak in Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

It seems that configuring Keycloak is impossible to do in new version of Spring Boot 3 and Spring Security.

I tried writing SecurityFilterChain but first it skipped the whole Chain and allowed everyone who has valid bearer token to view protected resource.

I found out that Spring Boot isn't picking up roles and putting them in *Granted Authorities*, just scope from JWT. Is it good idea to write my own token converter?

`WebSecurityConfig.java`

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception  {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/api/**","api/**","/api").hasAuthority(ADMINISTRATION)
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(OAuth2ResourceServerProperties oAuth2ResourceServerProperties) {
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(oAuth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt().getJwkSetUri()).build();
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(oAuth2ResourceServerProperties.getJwt().getIssuerUri()));
        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    private static final String ADMINISTRATION = "ROLE_administration";
}
```

When I added `@Configuration` annotation to the Class all requests were rejected.
Here are the classes if you need them to answer the question.

`JwtAuthConverter.java`

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {
    private final JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    private final JwtAuthConverterProperties properties;
    public JwtAuthConverter(JwtAuthConverterProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = Stream.concat(
                jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter.convert(jwt).stream(),
                extractResourceRoles(jwt).stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities, getPrincipalClaimName(jwt));
    }

    private String getPrincipalClaimName(Jwt jwt) {
        String claimName = JwtClaimNames.SUB;
        if (properties.getPrincipalAttribute() != null) {
            claimName = properties.getPrincipalAttribute();
        }
        return jwt.getClaim(claimName);
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractResourceRoles(Jwt jwt) {
        Map<String, Object> resourceAccess = jwt.getClaim("resource_access");
        Map<String, Object> resource;
        Collection<String> resourceRoles;
        if (resourceAccess == null
                || (resource = (Map<String, Object>) resourceAccess.get(properties.getResourceId())) == null
                || (resourceRoles = (Collection<String>) resource.get("roles")) == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }
        return resourceRoles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

`JwtAuthConverter.java`

```java
@Data
@Validated
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jwt.auth.converter")
public class JwtAuthConverterProperties {

    @NotBlank
    private String resourceId;
    private String principalAttribute;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3)

Comment: @OctaviaAdler yes, I just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make custom JWT converter to extract Authorities from Keycloaks nested structure:

```json
"realm_access": {
        "roles": [
            "offline_access",
            "uma_authorization"
        ]
    }
```

This is an example of that class (you can use it to get other claims like email, username, ...):

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter;
    private JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter;


    public CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        this.jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        this.jwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    }
    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(Jwt jwt) {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = extractAuthorities(jwt);

        return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities);
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Jwt jwt) {
        if(jwt.getClaim("realm_access") != null) {
            Map<String, Object> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<String> roles = mapper.convertValue(realmAccess.get("roles"), new TypeReference<List<String>>(){});
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String role : roles) {
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
            }

            return authorities;
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

After that you include it in SecurityFilterChain and define which paths you want to secure:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasAuthority(SOMEROLE)
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
        );
        http.oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new CustomJwtAuthenticationConverter());
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    private static final String SOMEROLE = "SOMEROLE";
}
```