# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0 : authenticationManager cannot be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, reactive

I'm getting the below error after I try to implement the SecurityWebFilterChain for the reactive application. I think this could be related to the dependency versioning issue because without WebSecurityConfiguration class changes the application started fine.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.WebFluxSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setSecurityWebFilterChains' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/test123/test123/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:768) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]
    at com.test123.test123.Test123Application.main(Test123Application.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [com/test123/test123/security/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null
```

Web security configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/test").permitAll()
//                .and().formLogin().authenticationFailureHandler((exchage, exception) -> Mono.error(exception))
                        .and().httpBasic();
//                .and().oauth2ResourceServer().authenticationManagerResolver(customAuthenticationManager());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

pom.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test123</groupId>
    <artifactId>test123</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test123</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring.cloud-version>2021.0.5</spring.cloud-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>8.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

One other thing I noticed when I removed the oauth2 resource server dependency the application is starting fine. but since i want to implement custom authentication manager i need that dependency as well

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What is in your application.properties? You request your app to be both a resource-server and a client (you declared dependencies on both starters). Is it intentional?

Comment: Hi @ch4mp Thanks for the comment, yeah it acts as a resource server as well as a client for the AWS Cognito. that's the feature I'm trying to implement here. Btw I was able to resolve the above mentioned issue that was related to the few of SecurityWebFilterChain that I have used and when I altered/changed the order of it the app started running but still it doesn't call the custom authentication manager that I implemented. For that I have to dig deeper I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to start the application without above mentioned error by changing/altering the SecurityWebFilterChains

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.csrf().disable().cors()
                .and().authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated()
.and().oauth2ResourceServer().authenticationManagerResolver(customAuthenticationManager());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Never disable CSRF protection if you do not also disable sessions (session creation policy = stateless)

Comment: The SecurityFilterChain defined here works for a resource-server only. If your app also is a client, you need a second SecurityFilterChain. Details in this other thread: [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830) (Keycloak VS Cognito just changes OIDC configuration URI and authorities claims name)