# Spring boot keycloak integration OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

Update: disabling client auth and authorization will not show the 401 message anymore but secured endpoints will return 403.

I'm trying to integrate keycloak core-version: 20.0.2 running from a docker container.
I've started out following https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
but after multiple suggestions from different threads I cannot get the integration to work.

application properties:

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=localhost:1337
keycloak.realm=SARServices
keycloak.resource=sar-login
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.credentials.secret=NvkAdEPqbN39ubjqtrjn7dKElgLlUNLj

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=sar-login
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=https://localhost:1337/realms/SARServices
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

WebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
class SecurityConfig(
    private val keycloakLogoutHandler: KeycloakLogoutHandler
) {

    @Bean
    fun keycloakConfigResolver(): KeycloakConfigResolver? {
        return KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver()
    }


    @Bean
    protected fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy {
        return RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(SessionRegistryImpl())
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/*")
            .hasRole("adventurer")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
        http.oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

keycloak server log:

```
2023-01-07 18:46:55 2023-01-07 17:46:55,045 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-65) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=7eec0241-e69f-4d5c-8b7f-7a96926e8315, clientId=sar-login, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code
```

docker compose:

```
version: '1'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=bn_keycloak
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bitnami_keycloak
    volumes:
      - 'postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql'
      - './certs:/etc/codelance/cert'

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start --hostname-port=1337
    ports:
      - "1337:8443"
    environment:
      - KC_HOSTNAME=localhost
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE=/etc/codelance/cert/keycloakcert.pem
      - KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE=/etc/codelance/cert/keycloak.pem
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    volumes:
      - './certs:/etc/codelance/cert'
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
```

Web response login after signing in:
[image]

client config:
[image][image]

Comment: Make keycloak.public-client=False instead of keycloak.public-client=True

Comment: assigned to false, the 401 error persists

Comment: Change keycloak.auth-server-url=https://localhost:1337 and if that does not work use host.docker.internal instead of localhost in the   keycloak.auth-server-url and spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri

Comment: Neither work, note that only Keycloak is running in a docker container.
I do see error events in the container (see original question).

Comment: Did you try first to deploy in KC on the host machine and then if it works move to the container? btw when you run the container did you publish the ports -p ?

Comment: About the ports I believe so: see added docker compose to thread question above.
I've never ran Keycloak natively on my machine always in a container.

Comment: @dreamcrash can confirm same issue happens with standalone version

Comment: Did you manage to solve this one?

Comment: @dreamcrash Yes and no, I followed along ch4mp his answer and it was clear that I was mixing concepts. I'm now using a resource-server in the correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [Keycloak adapters for Spring are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Don't use it.

Are you sure you want a client and not a resource-server? In other words, are your controller methods returning template names or JSON payloads?

My answer to this other question contains the solution for both client and resource-server: [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830)