# @KeycloakConfiguration implementing method missing

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm having issue about setting @KeycloakConfiguration, I watched keycloak's docs and it say that i have to create a class and set all the methods that are set in the documentation

Documentation Keycloak:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    /**
     * Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
     */
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Defines the session authentication strategy.
     */
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(buildSessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    protected SessionRegistry buildSessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/customers*").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

so i did, but when i copy and paste that in my class it says that i have to implements two more method of security configurer that are init(Builder:B) void and configure (Builder:B) void, other than that i already have a configure method.

I saw in the Docs but doesn't specify what i have to do with these two methods, i would like to know if I'm missing something or if is a feature of the last version of keycloak, the keycloak version that i'm using is the 20.0.2

my dependecies are this:

````
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2En6.png)
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>20.0.2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>```



 


As i say i would like to know what i have to do with these two methods
````

Answer (score 0):

Check [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3) or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak both resolved My problem with same issue