# Spring Boot with Spring Security and Keycloak only providing Anonymous Authentication Token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

so I followed a guide which set up Keycloak to secure my Spring Boot REST API with Spring Security. Previously, my application relied on a standard user details service to authenticate users. My code relies on being able to access the currently logged-in user's username. However, now that I switched to Keycloak, I only receive the username 'anonymousUser'.

How do I configure this correctly for the following code to return the preferred username:

`public static String getCurrentUsername() {`

`return (String) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();`

`}`

I tried to modify the configuration of the client and user on Keycloak, but even for example, adding roles has no effect. Spring Boot only returns the role of [ANONYMOUS_USER].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no chance you get any info about current user from `AnonymousAuthenticationToken`: this implementation of `Authentication` is put in security-context when the request was not successfully authorized (user could not be identified). This means that either:

- the wrong type of authorization (or no authorization at all) is attached to the request. This is the case for instance when an Bearer access token is provided but a session expected
- `SecurityFilterChain` bean(s) is (or are) misconfigured.

A quite common mistake lately is to write **client configuration** and then then send requests with `Bearer` header. When OAuth2 client conf (with `oauth2Login`) is used, incoming requests are authorized with session cookies, not access token. If you want the requests to your REST API be authorized with access tokens provided in a `Bearer` Authorization header, then you have to configure it as a **resource-server**.

Another common mistake relates to apps needing more than one authorization mechanism (OAuth2 client, OAuth2 resource server, Basic, etc.). In such cases, you should provide with a filter-chain bean for each. But if one of the first in `@Order`intercepts a request it shouldn't (misconfigured `securityMatcher`), then the security context initialization fails.

For basic info on how to configure Spring-boot 3 resource-server and client with Keycloak, see my answer to this question: [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830)

Spring-security default `Authentication` for successful OAuth2 authorization in resource-servers is `JwtAuthenticationToken` which return a `Jwt` instance as `principal`. You can get any access-token claim from this `Jwt` instance. Here is a sample with `preferred_username`. Open an access-token in a tool like https://jwt.io to find the name of the claim with the username value you are looking for (it could be as well `sub`, `email` or any private claim you configured in Keycloak)

```java
((Jwt) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getClaims().get(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME);
```

If you want `getPrincipal()` to return the username instead of a `Jwt` instance, you'll have to provide your own `Authentication` implementation. You might use `JwtAuthenticationToken` as a base (but this not the best option, see the note below):

```java
public class MyAuthentication extends JwtAuthenticationToken {
    public MyAuthentication(Jwt jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(jwt, authorities);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPrincipal() {
        return getToken().getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME);
    }   
}
```

Just adapt the `Jwt2AuthenticationConverter` from the answer I linked above

```java
@Bean
public Jwt2AuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter(Jwt2AuthoritiesConverter authoritiesConverter) {
    return jwt -> new MyAuthentication(jwt, authoritiesConverter.convert(jwt));
}
```

## Important note

You'd better use `authentication.getName()` instead of `authentication.getPrincipal()` to access username. `principal` is typed as `Object` in `Authentication` which makes your expressions very fragile: you can get absolutely any type of data as principal (depending on the type of authentication in the security context) and there are cases where you don't really control it (for instance with the `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` instance you currently have because of unauthorized request).

However, `JwtAuthenticationToken::getName` returns subject (`sub` claim), so you'll still have to provide your own `Authentication` implementation for successful authorizations to return `preferred_username` in a new @Override of `getName()`. `MyAuthentication` would then be:

```java
public class MyAuthentication extends JwtAuthenticationToken {
    public MyAuthentication(Jwt jwt, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(jwt, authorities);
    }
    
    //Note that this time getName() is overriden instead of getPrincipal()
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getToken().getClaimAsString(StandardClaimNames.PREFERRED_USERNAME);
    }   
}
```

Use the same `Jwt2AuthenticationConverter` bean to switch from default `JwtAuthenticationToken` to `MyAuthentication` in case of successful request authorization.