# Migrate from KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to Spring Security 6

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm migrating a project from Spring 5.x to Spring 6 that previously used the KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which is now [no longer supported](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/02/adapter-deprecation). I've searched the internet and found that I need to migrate to Spring Security's OAuth2 solutions instead of using the adapter. I've also found a [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3) that tackles this question in the context of Spring Boot.

I don't have Spring Boot though, only Spring. I haven't found anything regarding the migration from the adapter to Spring Security without Spring Boot. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just as when you don't use any other spring-boot module: you write by yourself what is auto-configured by spring-boot.

Refer to spring-boot documentation to figure out what beans are auto-configured in the case of the accepted answer to the question you linked (or to spring-security documentation to setup a resource-server with JWT decoder and custom authentication converter for roles mapping).