# How to customize 401 Unauthorized and 403 Forbidden HTTP responses when using Keycloak and Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I get the following failure responses which the responses themselves are correct:

- An `HTTP 401 Unauthorized` with empty body when the Keycloak token is
  invalid or expired.
- An `HTTP 403 Forbidden` with stack trace in body when access is denied.

But how can one generate custom responses instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to customize responses in the following way:

A class with arbitrary name which implements `AuthenticationFailureHandler` and `AccessDeniedHandler` interfaces:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakCookieBasedRedirect;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler;
// ... other required imports


@Component
public class CustomSecurityFailureResponseHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandler, AccessDeniedHandler {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    // The body of this method has been copied from its Keycloak counterpart, except for the marked line.
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException {
        if (!response.isCommitted()) {
            if (KeycloakCookieBasedRedirect.getRedirectUrlFromCookie(request) != null) {
                response.addCookie(KeycloakCookieBasedRedirect.createCookieFromRedirectUrl(null));
            }
            writeResponse(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Authentication failed");  // <--- marked line
        } else {
            if (200 <= response.getStatus() && response.getStatus() < 300) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Success response was committed while authentication failed!", exception);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException {
        writeResponse(response, HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN, "Access denied");
    }

    private void writeResponse(HttpServletResponse response, int status, String message) throws IOException {
        
        // Generate your intended response here, e.g.:
        
        response.setStatus(status);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        response.getOutputStream().println(
                objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                        .writeValueAsString(new MessageResponse(status, message)));
    }
    
    record ResponseMessage(int statusCode, String message) {}    
}
```

in the keycloak security config:

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@Import(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // An object of preceding class is injected here
    private final CustomSecurityFailureResponseHandler customSecurityFailureResponseHandler;

    // Other required methods has been omitted for brevity
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(customSecurityFailureResponseHandler); // for 403 Forbidden
    }

    // This method is overridden to customize 401 Unauthorized response
    @Override
    public KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter() throws Exception {

        KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = super.keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customSecurityFailureResponseHandler);

        return filter;
    }
}
```

The method `keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter()` is overridden to replace favorable `AuthenticationFailureHandler`.

The `Keycloak 19.0.3` and the `Spring boot 2.7.4` have been used.

I hope this workaround helps someone.
Any better solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the error code you receive back using something like this:

```
int error = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Then you can check the error if it triggers and display your own error:

```
if (error == 404)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "custom message here", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keycloak adapters used in @Askar answer [are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187) and will probably never be compatible with boot 3. Don't use it. Alternative in the accepted answer to ["Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732) (applicable to boot 2.6 and 2.7 with very little modification).

Here is sample of authentication exception customization in `HttpSecurity` configuration. You might do about anything with the response:

```java
http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((request, response, authException) -> {
    response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, "Basic realm=\"Restricted Content\"");
    response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
});
```

Comment: Good point, actually we are near to the end of current project. Certainly we will try `spring-security OAuth2` at the next project.