# How to map authorities in spring-boot OAuth2 client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, oauth-2.0

I'm building a standard spring boot mvc + thymeleaf + Oauth2. So far I added the oauth2-client lib for authentication purpose but now I need authorization to protect my app.

Does it mean I also need to configure it as a resource server?

If not, how can I map authorities from the private claim (in the ID token) my authorization-server puts roles into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource-server configuration is adapted to secure REST resources.

Client configuration is just fine unless you expose your API. If so, add a second security filter-chain. Details in this other answer: [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732)

#### Authorities mapping in OAuth2 client

As mentioned in my comment, [Spring-security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper) is always better than whatever one on Stackoverflow could write (but Spring-security team members of course, who happen to post answers)

Double check the claim in which your authorization-server puts user roles into and provide an authorities mapper, either:

- explicitly with `http.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapper());`
- as a `@Bean` of type `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` which should be auto-configured by spring-boot

In both cases, the code for the mapper is the same (double check the name of the claim for user roles with your authorization-server, but it might be `groups` with Azure AD):

```java
@Bean
GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
    return (authorities) -> {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
            if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority oidcAuth) {
                oidcAuth.getIdToken().getClaimAsStringList("groups").forEach(a -> mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a)));

            } else if (authority instanceof OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2Auth) {
                ((List<String>) oauth2Auth.getAttributes().getOrDefault("groups", List.of())).forEach(a -> mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(a)));

            }
        });

        return mappedAuthorities;
    };
}
```

Comment: ok so I should be able to validate the authorization just with my id token right?

Comment: where I can set the claim field name to look for the roles?

Comment: Better to ask god than his disciples: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html#webflux-oauth2-login-advanced-map-authorities-grantedauthoritiesmapper

Comment: I edited your question so that, I believe, others with same need have better chance to open the thread. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Im getting **403** when protecting all requests, any ideia?
`http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize .anyRequest().hasRole("admin"));`

Comment: maybe have you exactly `admin` in your access token => either add `ROLE_` prefix in the mapper or use `hasAuthority("admin")` instead of `hasRole("admin")` (for Spring, a role is nothing more than an authority starting with `ROLE_`)

Comment: it is all set but still doesnt work, I noticed when using the SecurityFilterChain the GrantedAuthoritiesMapper didnt get invoked

Comment: GrantedAuthoritiesMapper with @Bean annotation didnt work, but if I set that into the oauth2Login it works