# Multi-tenant Spring Webflux microservice with Keycloak OAuth/OIDC

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-webflux, multi-tenant

**Use Case:**

- I am building couple of reactive microservices using spring webflux.
- I am using Keycloak as authentication and authorization server.
- Keycloak realms are used as tenants where tenant/realm specific clients and users are configured.
- The client for my reactive microservice is configured in each realm of Keycloak with the same client id & name.
- The microservice REST APIs would be accessed by users of different realms of Keycloak.
- The APIs would be accessed by user using UX (developed in React) publicly as well as by other webflux microservices as different client internally.
- The initial part of the REST API would contain tenant information e.g. *http://Service-URI:Service-Port/accounts/Keycloak-Realm/Rest-of-API-URI*

**Requirements:**

- When the API is called from UX, I need to invoke authorization code grant flow to authenticate the user using the realm information present in the request URI. The user (if not already logged in) should be redirected to the login page of correct realm (present in the request URI)
- When the API is called from another webflux microservice, it should invoke client credential grant flow to authenticate and authorize the caller service.

**Issue Faced:**

- I tried to override `ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver` as below:

```
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.ReactiveJwtDecoders;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class TenantAuthenticationManagerResolver implements ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> {
    private static final String ACCOUNT_URI_PREFIX = "/accounts/";
    private static final String ACCOUNTS = "/accounts";
    private static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";
    private final Map<String, String> tenants = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager> authenticationManagers = new HashMap<>();

    public TenantAuthenticationManagerResolver() {
        this.tenants.put("neo4j", "http://localhost:8080/realms/realm1");
        this.tenants.put("testac", "http://localhost:8080/realms/realm2");
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ReactiveAuthenticationManager> resolve(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just(this.authenticationManagers.computeIfAbsent(toTenant(exchange), this::fromTenant));
    }

    private String toTenant(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        try {
            String tenant = "system";
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            String path = request.getURI().getPath();
            if (path.startsWith(ACCOUNT_URI_PREFIX)) {
                tenant = extractAccountFromPath(path);
            }
            return tenant;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }

    private JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager fromTenant(String tenant) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.tenants.get(tenant))
                .map(ReactiveJwtDecoders::fromIssuerLocation)
                .map(JwtReactiveAuthenticationManager::new)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown tenant"));
    }

    private String extractAccountFromPath(String path) {
        String removeAccountTag = path.replace(ACCOUNTS, EMPTY_STRING);
        int indexOfSlash = removeAccountTag.indexOf("/");
        return removeAccountTag.substring(indexOfSlash + 1, removeAccountTag.indexOf("/", indexOfSlash + 1));
    }
}
```

- Then I used the overridden TenantAuthenticationManagerResolver class in to `SecurityWebFilterChain` configuration as below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    TenantAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver;

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/health").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Client()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

- Blow is the configuration in `application.properties`:

```
server.port=8090
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.provider=keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=test-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=ZV4kAKjeNW2KEnYejojOCsi0vqt9vMiS
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
```

- When I call the API using master realm e.g. http://localhost:8090/accounts/master/health it redirects the user to Keycloak login page of master realm and once I put the user id and password of a user of master realm, the API call is successful.
- When I call the API using any other realm e.g. http://localhost:8090/accounts/realm1/health it still redirects the user to Keycloak login page of master realm and if I put the user id and password of a user of realm1 realm, the login is not successful.

So it seems that multi-tenancy is not working as expected and it is only working for the tenant configured in `application.properties`.

- What is missing in my implementation w.r.t. multi-tenancy?
- How to pass the client credentials for different realms?
- I tried to use JWKS in place of client credentials but somehow it is not working. Below is the configuration used for JWKS in `application.properties`.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.keystore=C:\\Work\\test-client.jks
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.keystore-type=JKS
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.keystore-password=changeit
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.key-password=changeit
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.key-alias=proactive-outreach-admin
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.truststore=C:\\Work\\test-client.jks
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.truststore-password=changeit
```

**Note:** JWKS is not event working for master realm configured in `application.properties`.

Need help here as I am stuck for many days without any breakthrough. Let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: I'm curious, have you just tried the solution proposed in the answer below (probably the only you'll ever get)?

Answer (score -1):

#### Client V.S. resource-server configuration

As a reminder, clients consume resources (send REST requests) and resource-servers serve resources (respond to this REST requests).

**Tokens acquisition and refreshing is the responsibility of clients, not resource-servers.**

Your REST API, being an OAuth2 resource-server, should not care about login, logout nor OAuth2 flows. From its point of view, all that matters is if a request is authorized with an access-token emitted by one of the issuers (tenants) it trusts. **Remove `.oauth2Client()` and `.oauth2Login()` from your resource-server security filter-chain.**

`WebClient`, `@FeignClient`, `RestTemplate` or whatever you use for inter micro-service requests are OAuth2 clients. It should be configured with either client-credentials (to emit requests in its own name) or forward the access-token from the original request (to emit a request on behalf of the authenticated user).

Your React app might be an OAuth2 "public" client. An other option is adopting the BFF pattern where the application in the browser in not OAuth2 at all (it is secured with good old session) and a middleware on the server (possibly spring-cloud-gateway) is the OAuth2 client, keeping the tokens and translating security from session to access-token before forwarding requests to resource-server. In both cases (public client and BFF) the OAuth2 client will use `authorization-code` flow to authenticate users and then `refresh-token` to maintain valid access-tokens. **The user redirection to the authorization-server should be initiated by the OAuth2 client and the authorization-code should be returned to this same client**.

- If you choose to implement a public client in React, use a client lib for that (search with `React` associated with either `OAuth2`, `OpenID` or `OIDC`)
- If you choose the BFF pattern, refer to the doc of the implementation you pick (spring-cloud-gateway can be configured with spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client).

An app needs to be both a client with `.oauth2Login()` and a resource-server only when it serves server-side rendered UI (with Thymeleaf, JSF and so on) and publicly exposes a REST API. In that case, define two separated security filter-chains as exposed in this other answer: [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732)

#### Multi-tenancy in Webflux resource-server with JWT decoder

You already follow the recommended way to implement multi-tenancy on a resource-server: override the default authentication-manager resolver with one capable of providing the right authentication-manager depending on the request: `http.oauth2ResourceServer().authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)`

I'm not sure using a part of the request path is the best option: a JWT comes with an `issuer` claim which precisely contains which authorization-server emitted this token. This is the way I implement in [`spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server`](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.c4-soft.springaddons/spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server/6.0.16) (a thin wrapper around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`).

Last your code is probably missing an authorities converter (to get authorities from Keycloak `realm_access.roles` instead of `scope`) and possibly it would be better to use `preferred_username` rather than `subject` as username.

#### Complete solution with `spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webflux-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthorizeExchangeSpecPostProcessor authorizeExchangeSpecPostProcessor() {
        return (ServerHttpSecurity.AuthorizeExchangeSpec spec) -> spec
                .pathMatchers("/health").hasRole("USER")
                .anyExchange().authenticated();
    }
}
```

```yaml
neo4j: http://localhost:8080/realms/realm1
neo4j-client: test-client
testac: http://localhost:8080/realms/realm2
testac-client: test-client

allowed-origins: 
- https://localhost
- https://localhost:8100
- https://localhost:4200

com:
  c4-soft:
    springaddons:
      security:
        cors:
        - path: /**
          allowed-origins: ${allowed-origins}
        issuers:
        - location: ${neo4j}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
            claims:
            - realm_access.roles
            - resource_access.${neo4j-client}.role
        - location: ${testac}
          username-claim: preferred_username
          authorities:
            claims:
            - realm_access.roles
            - resource_access.${testac-client}.role
        permit-all: 
        - "/health/readiness"
        - "/health/liveness"
```

No, I did not forget authentication-manager resolver nor security filter-chain bean with resource-server config, everything is auto-configured from properties. Also, user name and roles should be mapped correctly.

**At this point, the REST API should accept request with access-token emitted by any of the configured issuers**. Use Postman or any other OAuth2 REST client to try (not your browser).

#### Configuring `WebClient` with client-credentials

Expose such a bean:

```java
@Bean
WebClient webClient(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                    clientRegistrationRepository,
                    authorizedClientService));
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("internal");
    return WebClient.builder().apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration()).build();
}
```

With such properties (mind the `authorization-grant-type` value):

```yaml
internal: http://localhost:8080/realms/realm1

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          internal:
            issuer-uri: ${internal}
        registration:
          internal:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: internal
            client-secret: change-me
            provider: internal
            scope: 
            - openid
            - offline_access
```

#### Adding client filterchain

If you add client configuration just for OAuth2 login because you try to issue a GET request with your browser, read the first section again and forget about that. Instead, require actual OAuth2 clients to authorize their requests and use a REST client for your tests (capable of fetching tokens and sending GET requests as well as POST, PUT, and DELETE ones). Again, it is client business to handle OAuth2 flows to acquire access-tokens.

But if your application also hosts server-side rendered UI (Thymeleaf, JSP, etc.), then, as exposed in the solution linked above, add a second security filter-chain for your client resources. With "my" starter, just add:

- those two beans to the `SecurityConfig`:

```java
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain uiFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerProperties serverProperties, GrantedAuthoritiesMapper authoritiesMapper)
        throws Exception {
    http.securityMatcher(
            new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                    // UiController pages
                    new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/ui/**"),
                    // those two are required to access Spring generated login page
                    // and OAuth2 client callback endpoints
                    new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/login/**"),
                    new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/oauth2/**")));

    http.oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/login/**", "/oauth2/**").permitAll().anyExchange().authenticated();

    return http.build();
}

/**
 * @param  authoritiesConverter We are in spring-addons, we have a {@link ConfigurableClaimSet2AuthoritiesConverter} in the context!
 * @return                      a mapper from oauth2Login result to granted authorities
 */
@Bean
GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper(Converter<Map<String, Object>, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>> authoritiesConverter) {
    return (authorities) -> {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        authorities.forEach(authority -> {
            if (authority instanceof OidcUserAuthority oidcAuth) {
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(authoritiesConverter.convert(oidcAuth.getIdToken().getClaims()));

            } else if (authority instanceof OAuth2UserAuthority oauth2Auth) {
                mappedAuthorities.addAll(authoritiesConverter.convert(oauth2Auth.getAttributes()));

            }
        });

        return mappedAuthorities;
    };
}
```

- and those properties to the yaml file above:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          neo4j:
            issuer-uri: ${neo4j}
          testac:
            issuer-uri: ${testac}
        registration:
          neo4j-client: 
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${neo4j-client}
            client-secret: change-me
            provider: neo4j
            scope: 
            - openid
            - offline_access
          testac-client: 
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ${testac-client}
            client-secret: change-me
            provider: neo4j
            scope: 
            - openid
            - offline_access
```

Now, OAuth2 login generated page should prompt for which client to use. As clients are configured with different issuers, the client is now multi-tenant too.

Note that the conf above assumes that both clients will use authorization-code flow.