# Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot service that is secured via a Keycloak server. I get the status code "404 Not Found" for every request with no log entries in the Spring Boot Server. So my guess was that the controller classes are not found. I added @ComponentScan annotation and since then I get the error message *"Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json"*. No matter if the file exists or not.
I want to read all properties from the application.properties file and I don't need the keycloack.json file.

I am grateful for any tip.

**main:**

```
@Import({ WebSecurityConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.company.xy.controller","com.company.xy.client"})
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://database:5432/db
spring.datasource.username=db
spring.datasource.password=db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect


server.port=8585

keycloak.realm=realm
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180
keycloak.resource=resource
keycloak.credentials.secret=abc
keycloak.credentials.username=adm
keycloak.credentials.password=password
keycloak.credentials.provider=secret

keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.1</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-keycloak</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <name>spring-boot-keycloak</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Keycloak</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>11</java.version>
      <keycloak.version>17.0.0</keycloak.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
         <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
         <version>19.0.3</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

**error message**

```
2023-02-24 09:31:56.249 ERROR 8052 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at com.company.xy.Application.Application.main(Application.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:473) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:206) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter' defined in com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:175) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:170) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:87) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:260) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:234) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'adapterDeploymentContext' defined in com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.afterPropertiesSet(KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:134) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext]: Factory method 'adapterDeploymentContext' threw exception; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.loadKeycloakDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.java:83) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.java:76) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
        at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.adapterDeploymentContext(KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:72) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-17.0.0.jar:17.0.0]
        at com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c632c0df.CGLIB$adapterDeploymentContext$10(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c632c0df$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$45b88d07.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        at com.company.xy.security.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c632c0df.adapterDeploymentContext(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
        ... 70 common frames omitted
```

**I have already implemented the following class so that only the Spring Boot application.properties are used.:**

```
@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: Keycloak adapters for spring where deprecated in early 2022 and are not compatible with Spring Boot 3. Refer to this other answer for solution (it works with boot 2.6 too with almost no change) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732