# Extract Keycloak Principal in spring boot 3 using oauth

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak, spring-security-rest

is there any way to extract Keycloak Principal in spring boot 3 using oauth?

With older version we accessed like below,

```
 KeycloakAuthenticationToken authentication;
  try {
     authentication =
             (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  } catch (ClassCastException exception) {
     throw new UnauthorizedException("Missing token");
  }
  Principal principal = (Principal) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public final static String TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME = "preferred_username";                                                                                                  
Authentication authToken = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Map<String, Object> attributes = Collections.emptyMap();
attributes = ((JwtAuthenticationToken) authToken).getTokenAttributes();
String userName = (String) attributes.get(TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak's legacy API is already deprecated. You don't need `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` for extracting principal. Use standard spring oauth2 code like

```
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(authentication !=null) {
          Principal principal = (Principal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        }
```

Comment: Actually, it's not "I think", it's "it was a year ago". Adapters are not compatible with Boot 3 at all. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3

Comment: removed I think :)