# insufficient_scope error while using Keycloak with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I use keycloak with Spring Boot api rest, but I get this error:

> Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

I believe this token is valid.

Code:

```
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        System.out.println("Entro a seguridad");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/all/**")
            .hasAnyRole("user_roles")
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll();
        http.oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .addLogoutHandler((LogoutHandler) keycloakLogoutHandler)
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
```

[jwt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExaSI.png)

I expect the token works. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have the same problem during tests using REST-assured + Testcontainers + Keycloak.
I receive `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token.", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"`
Only one difference I can see between real JWT token and token generated by testcontainers-keycloak is order in field `scope`.
The real valid token has value `"email profile"` during in test this has `"profile email"`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you have not configured an authentication converter, which means the spring authorities are mapped from the scope claim with `SCOPE_` prefix (and not Keycloak private claims with `ROLE_` prefix which is required by `hasRole`).

What you need is change your resource-server configuration to `http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(...))` and provide an authentication converter mapping authorities from `realm_access.roles` (adding `ROLE_` prefix), and then build a `JwtAuthenticationToken` from it. Samples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732) and [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote (and my bet is you should read the introduction README).