# Role mapping is not working in spring boot integrated with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have created a spring boot application in which is integrated with keycloak and I am using oauth2.0 as resource server. In that application user is getting authenticated but the role is coming as null . I have used spring boot version 3.1.1 and keycloak version 21.0.1 and jwtauthconverter i am using.

I am excepting that role should be decoded by the spring boot through keycloak

Comment: Show use some code

Comment: We have no element to spot the mistake in your conf and authorities mapping was answered many times already. Sample for keycloak there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.