# Keycloak securityContext is null

Tags: java, keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I am trying to fetch the user details of a logged in user :

I am passing the access token collected from :

```html
https://localhost:1099/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

while calling this endpoint :

```html
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class userDetails {

    @GetMapping(value = "/myresources", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String handleUserInfoRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Using HttpServletRequest to inspect authentication...");

        // Get the HttpSession from the request
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        // Get the Keycloak security context from the session attribute
        KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext) session.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());

        if (securityContext != null) {
            AccessToken token = securityContext.getToken();

            // Extract details from the token
            String userId = token.getId();
            String userName = token.getPreferredUsername();

            // Print security context details
            String securityContextDetails = "User ID: " + userId + "\n" +
                                           "Username: " + userName;

            System.out.println("Security Context Details:\n" + securityContextDetails);

            // Return a response
            return securityContextDetails;
        } else {
            return "No Keycloak Security Context found";
        }
    }


}
```

I have also tried to get the security context from httpServletRequest for secured users using this instead of the session as done above :

```html
  // Get the Keycloak security context from the request attribute
        KeycloakSecurityContext securityContext = (KeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());
```

However, I am getting "No Keycloak Security Context found" or security context is null, principal is null. How can I get the user details i.e. "preferrred_username" from the access token. Iam not using spring security and I am using embedded springboot keycloak version 21.0.0 . Thanks in advance for all the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak adapter for spring was deprecated long ago. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732) for alternatives.

Once your security conf is fixed, you should have an `Authentication` instance in the security context. The type of this `Authentication` will depend on the request being

- **anonymous** => `AbstractAuthenticationToken`
- authorized with a session on an **OAuth2 client** with `oauth2Login` => `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` having an `OAuth2User` as principal (in case of OIDC authorization servers like Keycloak, this interface is further specialized to `OidcUser`)
- authorized with an access token on an **OAuth2 resource server** => the default `Authentication` depends on the conf (and can be easily replaced with a custom implementation like Keycloak adapters were doing):

  - `JwtAuthenticationToken` when a JWT decoder is used
  - `BearerTokenAuthentication` when introspection is used (usually with "opaque" tokens, even if you can introspect a JWT)

The easiest way access this `Authentication` is with "magic" parameter for your controller method:

```java
@GetMapping("/me")
public Map<String, Object> getMe(Authentication auth) {
    // authorized request to a resource server with JWT decoder
    if (auth instance of JwtAuthenticationToken jwt) {
        return jwt.getTokenAttributes();
    }
    // authorized request to a resource server with introspection
    if (auth instance of BearerTokenAuthentication bearerToken) {
        return bearerToken.getTokenAttributes();
    }
    // authorized request to an OpenID client 
    if (auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauth && oauth.getPrincipal() instanceof OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal user) {
        return user.getAttributes();
    }
    // most probably an unauthorized request (anonymous)
    return Map.of();
}
```

Of course, you can also use the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` static accessor, but it is probably not as convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I dont plan to use 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'. In my example, the code snippet  manually retrieve the KeycloakSecurityContext from the HttpSession and extract user details from the AccessToken, without directly utilizing the Keycloak Spring Security Adapter. I am using springboot 2. Is there an another way to pull the currently logged in user details, without making any change to the security config ?  I am just trying to pull the user details, a controller mapping is not mandatory, just a method to achieve it. @ch4mp

Comment: Also, I am not using 'keycloak-spring-security-adapter' as well in my project.

Comment: I can pull the userinfo using "auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo" - However, I will have to feed the accessToken and  I cannot find a way to get the accessToken of the currently logged in user.

Comment: And with how exactly is that `KeycloakSecurityContext` (defined in keycloak-core) instantiated if you're not using the deprecated adapters? How is the HttpSession created if you're not using spring-security-oauth2-client (the boot starter is just a helper to configure this one)? How is this session populated with a `KeycloakSecurityContext` instance? Also you have to decide if you want requests to be authorized with sessions (with user details in `HttpSession`) or with access tokens (with user details as token claims)...

Comment: I'm gonna make my own promotion again (already did in the answer I linked), but you should probably read my [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) to clarify what you really want to configure.

Comment: I have nothing but "spring_security_core" in build.gradle  of my project. Its inspired from this : https://github.com/thomasdarimont/embedded-spring-boot-keycloak-server/blob/master/embedded-keycloak-server-spring-boot-support/src/main/java/com/github/thomasdarimont/keycloak/embedded/support/DynamicJndiContextFactoryBuilder.java

i am using accessTokens to verify users. I will give aread to your linked post. Authentication instance is always null in my case :  Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); -

Comment: securityContextHolder is always null. Link to what I tried : https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#n8ttl6dohbiapwv20zhti

Comment: is there a way to achieve it using Keycloak adapter, as I am still in springboot2

Comment: from the main readme of the repo you linked "The idea is to have a variant of Keycloak-X but based on Spring Boot instead of Quarkus". So basically, you are using a sample to **build an authorization server** (a Keycloak server). I hardly believe this is what you need -I'm almost sure you already have a Keycloak instance somewhere). Take a breath and learn OAuth2 basics before trying to use it.

Comment: **Forget about Keycloak adapters, it was deprecated two years ago.** Just understand OAuth2 actors responsibilities (client, resource server, authorization server and resource owner) and how flows work (a minimum of authorization_code, client_credentials and refresh_token). Once you understood that, you'll be able to adapt what you'll find in my tutorials to your older boot versions.

Comment: Thank you, I will go through them all. I will sove this problem some way or the other. I can see that there is no explicit security configi n my setup, something similar to this : https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app. I can see the OIDC endpoints. let me continue to try some other way on why the SecurityContect is null even after the user is authenticated. Thnaks, have a good day ahead.

Comment: also, keycloak eventlisteners are able to pull all the info such as user_id, preferred_username etc thats embedded in the token