# keycloak with spring boot version equal or higher 3.1.3

Tags: spring, keycloak

someone could help how to implement keycloak with spring boot version greater or equal 3.1.3, since I have a project with angular-keycloak-spring boot with version less than 3.0.0 where I use the class KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in the configuration to work with keycloack but the problem is that this class is deprecated for spring boot greater or equal to 3.0.0, there will be no more support for it, someone could explain or provide me a guide or tutorial project how I can implement the new update, thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Keycloak Spring Adapter with Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3)

Answer (score 0):

TO know the newest version of `spring-boot` not support `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extend this `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I mean it was deprecated.

Instead of using `org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter` i suggest you to use [Spring Boot oAuth2 Resource Server Starter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html), here you will work with oAuth2.0 resource server part
`Depend on abstractions, not on concretions`.

Also some good resources that can help you to do it:

[Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html)

[spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

For more details and any blockers in implementation of it feel free to ask a new question or find relevant answer on forum.

Comment: I appreciate your support, I will keep the topic open to any questions.do you know any tutorial project of the complete updated implementation or more complete guide ?

Comment: About tutorials, idk, just documentation and step by step, there is nothing difficult just something special and that is all also some articles about how to do it you can find on internet

Comment: thanks for your support, I will keep the topic open for any questions that may arise.

Comment: i`m agree with @ch4mp that new question =  new topic.

Answer (score 0):

I already exposed how to configure an OAuth2 resource server (and OAuth2 clients) with Keycloak in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732).

Please note that if your system architecture haven't changed for a while, it is probably not following the [latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390). Your Angular application should not be a "public" OAuth2 client authorizing its requests to a resource server with Bearer tokens. There should instead be a middleware on your server (a BFF):

- configured as an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login`
- replacing the session cookie (requests to an OAuth2 client are secured with sessions, not tokens) with the access token in session before forwarding a request to a resource server

I have written [a tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2) for configuring `spring-cloud-gateway` as BFF between an Angular app and a Spring REST API configured as an OAuth2 (stateless) resource server.

Comment: I appreciate the support, in my case I am not using the BBF pattern but a single centralized api for any platform or device, if I am not mistaken to implement the BBF pattern you must create an api and interface for each device or platform right, it is based on platform independent customization right? it will be advisable to apply the BBF pattern in any project can you give me some guidelines I am interested.

Comment: BFF acronym can be used for middleware with several purposes. I personally don't expose different APIs for different front-ends and use BFF solely for security purposes: Use a **confidential** client on my servers as thin layer in front of stateless resource servers and **hide tokens from front-ends devices**. The why is explained by Spring Security team in the ticket I linked and the how in my tutorial.

Comment: thanks for your support, I will keep the topic open for any questions that may arise.

Comment: New question, new topic, new answer. Otherwise, other users with same question won't find an answer. Also, I suggest you read the text that comes when you "over" the buttons left of answers.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what it requires for an answer to be acceptable or even just useful.