# Keycloak + spring boot role authentification not working

Tags: java, spring, authorization, keycloak

I'm developing a spring backend that uses a keycloak auth server. I'm struggeling to  get role based authorization to work. I have created a user "dev_admin" in my realm and have given him the realm role "admin". I have the endpoint "debuf/admin" which is only accessible for users with the admin role. My security config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

private final KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler;
SecurityConfig(KeycloakLogoutHandler keycloakLogoutHandler) {
    this.keycloakLogoutHandler = keycloakLogoutHandler;
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain clientFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
            auth
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/debug/public")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/debug/authenticated")).authenticated()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/debug/admin")).hasAnyRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .logout((conf) -> {
            conf.addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler);
            conf.logoutSuccessUrl("/index");
        })
        .build();
}
}
```

However, after I log in as the dev_admin user and try to access the admin endpoint, i returns error 403. This is from the spring console:

```
2023-09-10T19:44:54.653+02:00 TRACE 1400 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5f29c29e]
2023-09-10T19:44:54.653+02:00 TRACE 1400 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@5f29c29e] using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[ROLE_admin]]
2023-09-10T19:44:54.653+02:00 TRACE 1400 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [dev_admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=1blJDsXc37Pz3uyqygg43A, sub=413591c7-3213-40a4-be2d-82dc69fe1264, email_verified=true, iss=http://localhost:8081/realms/users, typ=ID, preferred_username=dev_admin, given_name=dev, nonce=f_D-DARLucc5Y0Uau8QLhgv2srTM0gK3MDA1zpaDXDM, sid=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, aud=[core-server], acr=1, azp=core-server, auth_time=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, name=dev admin, exp=2023-09-10T17:49:50Z, session_state=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, family_name=admin, iat=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, email=dev@admin.com, jti=a7e9ff04-2526-4ff8-82c1-1216ee6d673a}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=95CD2FEF619B032D2A30C89CFAD0740C], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2023-09-10T19:44:54.653+02:00 TRACE 1400 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [dev_admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=1blJDsXc37Pz3uyqygg43A, sub=413591c7-3213-40a4-be2d-82dc69fe1264, email_verified=true, iss=http://localhost:8081/realms/users, typ=ID, preferred_username=dev_admin, given_name=dev, nonce=f_D-DARLucc5Y0Uau8QLhgv2srTM0gK3MDA1zpaDXDM, sid=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, aud=[core-server], acr=1, azp=core-server, auth_time=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, name=dev admin, exp=2023-09-10T17:49:50Z, session_state=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, family_name=admin, iat=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, email=dev@admin.com, jti=a7e9ff04-2526-4ff8-82c1-1216ee6d673a}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=95CD2FEF619B032D2A30C89CFAD0740C], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]]
2023-09-10T19:44:54.653+02:00 TRACE 1400 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending OAuth2AuthenticationToken [Principal=Name: [dev_admin], Granted Authorities: [[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]], User Attributes: [{at_hash=1blJDsXc37Pz3uyqygg43A, sub=413591c7-3213-40a4-be2d-82dc69fe1264, email_verified=true, iss=http://localhost:8081/realms/users, typ=ID, preferred_username=dev_admin, given_name=dev, nonce=f_D-DARLucc5Y0Uau8QLhgv2srTM0gK3MDA1zpaDXDM, sid=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, aud=[core-server], acr=1, azp=core-server, auth_time=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, name=dev admin, exp=2023-09-10T17:49:50Z, session_state=fab4e120-b249-4e76-bffb-c5a4820fa536, family_name=admin, iat=2023-09-10T17:44:50Z, email=dev@admin.com, jti=a7e9ff04-2526-4ff8-82c1-1216ee6d673a}], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=95CD2FEF619B032D2A30C89CFAD0740C], Granted Authorities=[OIDC_USER, SCOPE_email, SCOPE_openid, SCOPE_profile]] to access denied handler since access is denied
```

I also checked the dev_admin JWT token by using the "impersonate" feature and the role is contaiend in the token. I also noticed that in my browser the token that was saved as a cookie is much shorter and does not contain the role. These are all the clues I have found but I still don't know why its not working. If someone knows, whats going on that would be very helpful.

EDIT: I'm not using keycloak adapters by the way. it just looks like that because of the "keycloaklogouthandler" which sends a request to keycloaks logout endpoint

I should also mention that the client and resource server are the same server in my case. I think the problem has something to do with the security configuration. Here is my application.yml:

```
  security:
oauth2:
  resourceserver.jwt:
      issuer-uri: ${keycloak.baseUrl}/realms/${keycloak.userRealm}
      jwk-set-uri: ${keycloak.baseUrl}/auth/realms/${keycloak.userRealm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs

  client:
    registration.keycloak:
      client-id: myclient
      authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
      scope: openid

      admin_user: ???
      admin_password: ???

    provider.keycloak:
      issuer-uri: ${keycloak.baseUrl}/realms/${keycloak.userRealm}
      user-name-attribute: preferred_username
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual for an OAuth2 client with oauth2Login](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities), you should provide with a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` bean or override the `OAuth2UserService` (in the case of a [resource server with JWT decoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-authorization-extraction), you would provide a `Converter<Jwt, ? extends AbstractAuthenticationToken>`, maybe a manually configured `JwtAuthenticationConverter`).

**Do not use Keycloak adapters for Spring**. It was deprecated long ago and does not work with Spring Security 6 / Boot 3.

**Do not fetch user roles from Keycloak**. This is way too inefficient. Instead, read it from tokens. As you are writing an OAuth2 client (which reads the ID token, not the access token), you might have to activate the mappers: `Client scopes` -> `roles` -> `Mappers` -> `realm roles` and enable `Add to ID token` as well as `Add to userinfo` (you might do the same with client roles if you use it).

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732) contains sample conversion from Keycloak roles to Spring authorities in both resource servers and clients.

Comment: I have done some more debugging and the problem seems to be that the JWT spring checks for authorities is the ID token which doesnt actually contain any roles. I should also mention that my resource server and client are the same, the spring securty config is the one in my post.  I think I didnt configure it properly. I'm editing the post to provide more info

Comment: Read my answer again, you'll find the recipe to add roles to ID tokens. You are using `oauth2Login` => requests are authorized with session cookie, not `Bearer` access token. In the other answer, follow the link the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) section of my tutorials.

Comment: Alright, I overrode the OAuth2UserService like in the manual and extracted the "realm_access" claim from the jwt token and mapped it to the user. I'm now able to secure my endpoints with roles. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Things usually get easier when you read the manual (and the entirety of an answer) ;)

Comment: I'm a little bit worried about something though. I have now added a resource server filter chain which uses springs resource server support and set the JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter. However, when I place a break point in the converter it never stops there. I'm worried it might not even validate my tokens properly. Any idea on how to test/debug this? Updated config here:  https://hastebin.com/share/paridiviyo.java

Comment: Read my [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#1-oauth2-essentials) again: when using `oauth2Login`, requests are authorized with session cookies, not `Bearer` authorization header. Your resource server security filter-chain can apply only to requests authorized with an access token.

Comment: Tokens are stored on the OAuth2 client, which in your case is your Spring application on the server, and all requests from your browser are authorized with the same session cookie that was set during login. Your browser has no access to tokens stored in session on the server.

Answer (score -1):

It seems there might be an issue with the way you're specifying the role in your `SecurityConfig`. To use role-based authorization with Keycloak, you need to specify the role using the Keycloak-specific role prefix. By default, Keycloak uses the `ROLE_` prefix for roles.

Here's how you can modify your `SecurityConfig` to use the correct role prefix:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/debug/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/debug/authenticated").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/debug/admin").hasRole("admin") // Use "hasRole" with the role name without "ROLE_" prefix
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .defaultSuccessURL("/success")
            .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index");
    }
}
```

In this modified configuration:

We extend `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to take advantage of Keycloak-specific features.

We configure the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` to use the `keycloakAuthenticationProvider` provided by Keycloak.

Make sure that your Keycloak realm configuration matches this setup, especially regarding the role name. The role in Keycloak should be named "admin" without the `ROLE_` prefix.

Hope I was helpful.

Additionally, ensure that the Keycloak client configuration for your Spring Boot application includes the correct roles mapping.

After these modifications, try accessing the `/debug/admin` endpoint again. If the role is correctly assigned in Keycloak and your Keycloak client configuration is accurate, role-based authorization should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really help since I'm not using a keycloak adapter (apparently its deprecated). I use keycloaks REST API instead. Thank you for the answer though

Comment: I can see, so You need to implement logic (possibly in a custom service) to fetch the user's roles from Keycloak after authentication using the Keycloak REST API. You will need to make a request to Keycloak's /auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/{userId}/roles endpoint to obtain the user's roles.

Implement custom logic to compare the user's roles obtained from Keycloak with the required roles for each endpoint. You can use this logic to grant or deny access.

Comment: Hm if all else fails I suppose that is an option.

Comment: No, definitely not an option to consider. Keycloak adapters where deprecated almost two years ago and calling Keycloak API each time you need to access user roles is very inefficient. Instead, configure Keycloak to add roles to tokens and Spring Security to turn Keycloak roles into Spring authorities.