# Keycloak example Required a bean of type 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I config a simple example about keycloak using keycloak-spring-boot-starter 17.0.1
But when i use KeycloakSpringBootProperties like this

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KeycloakServiceImpl implements KeycloakService {
    private final KeycloakSpringBootProperties keycloakSpringBootProperties;

    @Value("${user-keycloak}")
    private String keycloakUsername;

    @Value("${password-keycloak}")
    private String keycloakPassword;

    @Override
    public Keycloak getKeycloak() {
        return Keycloak.getInstance(
                keycloakSpringBootProperties.getAuthServerUrl(),
                keycloakSpringBootProperties.getRealm(),
                keycloakUsername,
                keycloakPassword,
                keycloakSpringBootProperties.getResource(),
                (String) keycloakSpringBootProperties.getCredentials().get("secret"));
    }
}
```

this error occur
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in vn.com.mbbank.steady.user.service.impl.KeycloakServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties' in your configuration.

Does anyone have any solution?

Comment: Keycloak Spring Boot adapters where deprecated two years ago. Just don't use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732

Answer (score 0):

Either you are missing `@Configuration` or any other annotation on your `KeycloakSpringBootProperties` class, or you didn't enabled them on your configuration class with `@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)`