# How do I configure Spring to retrieve the OIDC user?

Tags: spring, keycloak, openid-connect

What do I need to do to get the user's OIDC or some information about the current session?

In my program I use Keycloak as an authorization provider.

My SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.addFilterAfter(createPolicyEnforcerFilter(),
                BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.sessionManagement(
                t -> t.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        );
        return http.build();
    }

    private ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter createPolicyEnforcerFilter() {
        return new ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter(new ConfigurationResolver() {
            @Override
            public PolicyEnforcerConfig resolve(HttpRequest request) {
                try {
                    return JsonSerialization.
                            readValue(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/policy-enforcer.json"),
                                    PolicyEnforcerConfig.class);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

policy-enforcer.json:

```
{
  "realm": "kasia",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:9090",
  "resource": "kasia-security",
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "fHW7Vm6lnNUp3Cmm4IcYbnHlIq5CZ69Z"
  },
  "paths" : [
    {
      "path": "/test/api/public",
      "enforcement-mode": "DISABLED"
    },{
      "path": "/swagger-ui/*",
      "enforcement-mode": "DISABLED"
    },{
      "path": "/v3/api-docs/*",
      "enforcement-mode": "DISABLED"
    }
  ]
}
```

My controller is where I should get the OIDC of the user:

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/user")
public ResponseEntity<?> testUser(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser user) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return ResponseEntity.ok("You have accessed the resource and you have the USER role");
}
```

At the moment my user is null and authentication contains the following data (no matter which account I log in with):

```
AnonymousAuthenticationToken [
Principal="anonymousUser",
Credentials=[PROTECTED],
Authenticated=true,
Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [
    RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1,
    SessionId=null
],
Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]
]
```

UPD. I also send the JWT token in my request:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJ6eTdPbVN1b3NTVGJCUlhEYnRzZFBtOUtDV3FBQWZhQy1iMzh6RHBVOTlVIn0.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.Uy26DtYh_d3vRXqSOosNxIp8qVKPKQtUiId6DqTPVAzO-YmDyDgx0QjdTtDEH9mZbA06qKSeRTgbaBkINAZG5I9GvAgFMrAyw1VJ-1cOu-sIr1JZHJDan4uDB2gn2CpOFC2OkXfu3RbrI6hrH7_POUN4v70oWeG1lb4oHMfXVwiAMMduaoNiMXDTNojB3O_3bd4L5DqgQYsvq5sB-FAqqe-XpqhUGLvQ8c26AYRyocDg5wG_9QsK1JaN4MljRqcGHXEYcKYJsc7R3kDDRjzjP-by_NR4ooTxdUkyInq4iAVZXTimrmP_RU4eTQWxfVowhs3BvFjllSHemJYTdyT63A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question: *"some information about the current session"* and in your conf: `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`. Do you get the inconsistency?

`OidcUser` is the principal of an `OAuth2AthenticationToken` on an OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login()` in an OIDC environment (authorized with sessions), when you are apparently trying to configure a resource server (REST API authorized with JWT).

Also, your `ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter` might be part of Keycloak adapters which were deprecated two years ago and [which aren't compatible with Spring Security 6 / Spring Boot 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74572732/619830)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I realized my mistake.

I would also like to say that ServletPolicyEnforcerFilter is compatible with Spring Security 6 / Spring Boot 3. This compatibility was introduced in keycloak version 23+

Comment: Well, I have missed this announcement. However, this probably comes with the usual drawbacks of policy enforcement on the authorization server: adherent to a particular vendor (try to switch to something else than Keycloak later on...) and, probably more important, introduces the load and latency of a call to the authorization server for each and every request on each and every resource server instance. Not to talk about the difficulty to unit-test access control and ensure that this rules are not altered at runtime.